# Spark JavaRDD Program to read csv and filter

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

How do I use `map` and `filter` function to read a csv file using RDD and select based on particular column using the csv file? Here is a sample csv file.

```
VendorID,tpep_pickup_datetime,tpep_dropoff_datetime,passenger_count,trip_distance,RatecodeID,store_and_fwd_flag,PULocationID,DOLocationID,payment_type,fare_amount,extra,mta_tax,tip_amount,tolls_amount,improvement_surcharge,total_amount

1,2017-07-01 00:06:25,2017-07-01 00:10:50,1,1.20,1,N,249,90,1,5.5,0.5,0.5,1.35,0,0.3,8.15
1,2017-07-01 00:20:04,2017-07-01 00:21:38,2,.20,1,N,249,158,2,3,0.5,0.5,0,0,0.3,4.3
1,2017-07-01 00:44:10,2017-07-01 00:59:29,1,4.30,1,N,100,45,1,15.5,0.5,0.5,3.35,0,0.3,20.15
1,2017-07-01 00:07:33,2017-07-01 00:31:30,1,8.30,1,N,138,162,1,27,0.5,0.5,6.8,5.76,0.3,40.86
```

I tried the below code, but I am don't know how to filter based on a particular column and fetch those related rows.

```
public class SparkUseCase{

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
    
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("CSV Reader").setMaster("local[*]");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        JavaRDD<String> allRows = sc.textFile("in/trip_yellow_taxi.data");
        System.out.println(allRows.take(5));
        List<String> headers = Arrays.asList(allRows.take(1).get(0).split(","));

        String field="VendorID";
        
        JavaRDD<String>dataWithoutHeaders = allRows.filter(x -> !(x.split(",")[headers.indexOf(field)]).equals(field));
        
        JavaRDD<Integer> VendorID = dataWithoutHeaders.map(x -> Integer.valueOf(x.split(",")[headers.indexOf(field)]));
                
        for (Integer i:VendorID.collect()){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        
      }
}
```

Appreciate your help.

UseCase: Filter all the records having RatecodeID as 4.

Comment: Using `collect()` in Spark defeats the point of using it as a library

Comment: yes i have used foreach instead of collect()

Answer (score 1):

Going with the current code, you would need to use the correct field name, not `VendorID`... Then use a filter again like you already did. Just check a different field

```
rdd.filter(x -> x.split(",")[index].equals("4"));
```

**However**, don't use Spark1 RDD and a "poor man's CSV parser" of `split(",")`.

Use the Spark2 csv reader with a Dataframe.

example in Scala

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate() 
val df = spark
  .read
  .format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .load("in/trip_yellow_taxi.data")

val rates4 = df.filter("RatecodeID == 4")
rates4.show(false)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this but i am forced to use JavaRDD for whatever reason the project needs them to be.

Comment: I'm not sure what reason that may be, but even Java supports DataFrames, and would be the encouraged way to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the SparkSession to read the CSV and query the data as per your requirement.

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("CDX JSON Merge Job")
                .getOrCreate();
Dataset<Row> csvDataset = spark.read().format("csv").option("header", "true")
                .load("C:\\sample.csv");
csvDataset.createOrReplaceTempView("csvdataTable");
Dataset<Row> reducedCSVDataset = spark.sql("select VendorID from csvdataTable limit 2 ");
Dataset<String> rdds = reducedCSVDataset.toDF().select("VendorID").as(Encoders.STRING());
List<String> listOfStrings = rdds.collectAsList();
listOfStrings.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));
```

Comment: By the way, question asked for `RatecodeID == 4` at the end. You can also do `csvDataset.toDF().select("VendorID")` without registering a temp view, at which point, it's basically the same as my answer, but `collectAsList` could be replaced with `rdds.show()`, or at the very least `rdds.forEach`

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, you are right. But, I just wanted to let the OP know that there are multiple ways to do this.